# Generate unique pairs of bi-directional data and use to count in Excel

Tags: excel, ms-office

I have a data-set containing:

```
Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3
   A          B         Good
   C          D         Good
   C          A         Bad
   D          B         Good
   B          A         Good
   A          B         Bad
   D          C         Bad
```

I want to know how many time the bi-directional combination of A B has produced a Good and a Bad, and this for all combinations (so C D, A C, B D etc).
Result should look something like:

```
Pair | Good | Bad
A B      2     1
C D      1     1
A C      0     1
ect.
```

The names of the pairs don't really matter, as long as we know the combination is either AB or BA.

How to I go about this?

Comment: you could try multiple index() with match() and count results... just an idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the Dynaic Array formula UNIQUE and FILTER:

Get the list:

```
=UNIQUE(IF(A2:A8<=B2:B8,A2:A8,B2:B8)&" "&IF(A2:A8>B2:B8,A2:A8,B2:B8))
```

Then using that output get the count:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(FILTER($C$2:$C$8,IF($A$2:$A$8<=$B$2:$B$8,$A$2:$A$8,$B$2:$B$8)&" "&IF($A$2:$A$8>$B$2:$B$8,$A$2:$A$8,$B$2:$B$8)=$E2)=F$1))
```

[image]

---

Without the Dynamic Array formula, to get the uique:

```
=INDEX(IF($A$2:$A$8<=$B$2:$B$8,$A$2:$A$8,$B$2:$B$8)&" "&IF($A$2:$A$8>$B$2:$B$8,$A$2:$A$8,$B$2:$B$8),AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($ZZ$1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,COUNTA(B2:B8)))/(COUNTIF($E$1:E1,IF($A$2:$A$8<=$B$2:$B$8,$A$2:$A$8,$B$2:$B$8)&" "&IF($A$2:$A$8>$B$2:$B$8,$A$2:$A$8,$B$2:$B$8))=0),1))
```

And to get the count:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((IF($A$2:$A$8<=$B$2:$B$8,$A$2:$A$8,$B$2:$B$8)&" "&IF($A$2:$A$8>$B$2:$B$8,$A$2:$A$8,$B$2:$B$8)=$E2)*($C$2:$C$8=F$1))
```

[image]

Comment: I am on Excel for Mac version 16.16.20. This lacks this function. I'll try to get hold of a Windows version later on.
Does this function by any chance come up with new pairs when they are added to the original data-set or is that a manual action in the 'PAIR' column?

Comment: @Arjan_IO The formula, as long as the references are for the entire data set, will automatically spill the unique pairs.  Dynamic Array Formula are only available with an Office 365 Subscription at the moment.

Comment: @ScottCraner That explains a lot! Very nice solution but unfortunately I can't use it ;(
Maybe one day MS decides to make it available to all ;)

Would the be a pivot-table like approach to this as well? Those are dynamic if one hits the refresh button

Comment: Ok, my first line works (E2). However, when I drag this down, I get A B, A B, B A, A B, #value, #value etc. So nothing further than these A and B characters. What am I missing?

Comment: There is something wrong with your use of the formula.  as you can see it works for me.  I am not sure as I cannot see your data set up. Try using Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode.  maybe your version requires that.

Comment: Can I drag this down or do I need to individually paste the formula in the cells?

Comment: Drag down @arjan_io

Comment: Got it working, thanks! Made a small typo converting the formula to a Dutch version ;)

Answer (score 1):

By-directional increases the number of cases:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A:A="A")*(B:B="B")*(C:C="Good"))+SUMPRODUCT((A:A="B")*(B:B="A")*(C:C="Good"))
```

[image]

*the other cases follow a similar pattern.*